# WCF RIA Error and Logging

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to add a WCF RIA service to an existing website.

When I load the page I get a  "Load Operation failed for query"

I fire up fiddler2 and get
    
    
        The resource cannot be found.

```
<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
        <br><br>

        <b> Requested URL: </b>/Services/WCSynthesis-Web-WCSynthDomainService.svc/binary<br><br>

        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>
```

So then I try to get  the WCF Loggging working 
but the Services is empty and so is the 
C:\Users\markgreenway\Desktop\My Dropbox\WCSynthesis\WCSynthesis.Web\Web_messages.svclog 
File

[alt text http://web7.twitpic.com/img/48823384-d9b0438ce6a54d9286856ee83dc8447a.4b227a17-scaled.jpg](http://web7.twitpic.com/img/48823384-d9b0438ce6a54d9286856ee83dc8447a.4b227a17-scaled.jpg)

So I cannot view anything in the  Service Trace Viewer

my System.Diagnostics

```
  <system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="C:\Users\markgreenway\Desktop\My Dropbox\WCSynthesis\WCSynthesis.Web\Web_messages.svclog"
    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
  <add initializeData="C:\Users\markgreenway\Desktop\My Dropbox\WCSynthesis\WCSynthesis.Web\Web_tracelog.svclog"
    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did add a reference to

•   Microsoft.RiaServices.Tools

and it started to work (Fiddler Gave me some real information)